# Google reCAPTCHA - ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key

Tags: asp.net, captcha, recaptcha

I see many issues here for the ERROR: Invalid domain for site key, but that is not my error - this is [image: my error]

"ERROR for site owner:
Invalid site key"

I'm implementing this in an ASP.NET 4.5 application. I've added the js to my html head, and I've added the div to the page as such:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mykey"></div>
```

This is straight off their site.

What I've tried: 
Delete and recreate key - no change

Enabling and disabling the "Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions" option in admin mode - no change

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Did you add the URL of the domain address? example : localhost

Comment: I have, I added them as 'mysite.org' etc.